# How can I optimize a VBA module that requires many calls to a subroutine?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing code for an Excel workbook provided by a client.

The purpose of this macro is to load the data for a customer into a sheet. When it does, the listener on one of the loaded cells is triggered, and it calls the appropriate subroutine associated with that customer's information.

The code is operating exactly as expected and completes in a few seconds. However, the client wishes us to perform this task on roughly 15,000 customers in sequence.

When we attempt to iterate the macro over roughly a hundred customers, the macro completes in a matter of a few minutes. However, when we increase the number of customers to around a thousand, the time to complete the run increases drastically.

I've been trying for days to optimize the subroutine itself, but the slowdown only arises when we are calling the subroutine upwards of a thousand times.

Why would repeated calls to the subroutine cause slowdown in the execution of the code, and is there a way that it can be mitigated?

```
Sub Looprun()

Dim n As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim SecondLastrow As Long
Dim Start As Long
Dim Finish As Long

Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set starting timestamp
Range("RunStart").Value = Now()

Start = Sheets("Reserve Summary").Range("L12").Value
Finish = Sheets("Reserve Summary").Range("L13").Value

lastRow = Cells(Sheets("Reserve Summary").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1

For n = Start To Finish
    
    Sheets("Calculation").Cells(3, 3).Value = n
' Cell C3 has a listener attached to it; see below. The customer's other information is loaded in via formulas that are keyed to cell C3.

    Sheets("Reserve Summary").Cells(n + 2, 3).Value = Sheets("Calculation").Range("C4").Value
    
    Sheets("Reserve Summary").Cells(n + 2, 5).Value = Sheets("Calculation").Range("Q25").Value
    
    Sheets("Reserve Summary").Cells(n + 2, 7).Value = Sheets("Calculation").Range("Q22").Value
    
Next

Range("RunEnd").Value = Now()

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.Calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim company As String

    If Target.Address = "$C$3" Then
    
        Worksheets("Calculation").Calculate
        
        company = Sheets("Calculation").Cells(3, 11).Value
        
        If LCase(company) = "A" Then
            Call SubroutineA
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        If LCase(company) = "B" Then
            Call SubroutineB
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        Call DefaultSubroutine
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: use variant arrays and limit the number of times the worksheet ranges are referenced.  Every time vba refers to the worksheet range it has to slow down to do so.  bulk loading and bulk assigning values where the number of references are limited allows vba to work at its own speed.

Comment: You will want to do the calculations in the script and not on the worksheet, again that is slow.

Comment: It is rather hard to say why code calling `SubroutineA` and `SubroutineB` is slow without seeing those subroutines.

Comment: @JohnColeman I am hesitant to put the actual subroutines in here since it is client work. The outer loop and listener are generic enough to not be an issue but it is a different story inside the routine. All three subroutines have been tested individually and complete in roughly 1-3 seconds on average. It's only when I call the outer loop and run it through a few thousand instances that vba begins visibly slowing down.

Comment: @ScottCraner Unfortunately that's client prerogative. I've mitigated this by turning off autocalc and doing a manual call to Sheets("Calculation).Calculate at the end of SubroutineA. Given the scope of the worksheet itself and the time constraints of the project, it's not feasible to migrate the on-sheet calculations into the module.
As for use of variant arrays, I recently learned about this and am in the process of integrating that into the subroutines. However, the problem is still persisting, and only when I make a large number of consecutive calls to the subroutines.

Comment: @NoviceFrost then your client will need to deal with the slowness.  The references to the worksheets is what is slowing it down.  If you cannot bulk load variant arrays and do the calculations in the code without going to the worksheet, then it will be slow.

Comment: @NoviceFrost it is a matter of addition.  The more times that one refers to the worksheet the more time it will take.  so in looping each time there is a reference to the worksheet it slows down in each loop.  These little slow downs adds up.  The more loops the more times the sheet is referenced the longer it takes.

Comment: @ScottCraner That all makes sense, and it's why I'm implementing arrays where I can. My question though is why the average time _per loop_ seems to be increasing when I increase the number of loops. When I run it for 100 policies, it takes slightly over a second per loop and finishes in 20 seconds. When I run it for 1000, performance substantially degrades. That's the piece that I'm having trouble trying to optimize. Is there some sort of memory leak, or some sort of pseudo-GC I should do at the end of the subroutine?

Comment: @NoviceFrost there is nothing you can do about that.  It is the fact that the tunnel to the worksheet is small and it it getting backed up.  Ideally what would happen is that you would change the subprocedures to functions  that accept and return arrays.  Then instead of the output being to a sheet it returns the full array for you to consume and parse.,